# Spring MVC: exception when serving a webm file

Tags: spring-mvc, webm

I have a Spring MVC (4.1.3) app running on Tomcat (8.0.30). I have the following in the context file:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/" />
```

Inside the res directory, I have a webm file.

When entering http://localhost/res/intro.webm, I am able to see the video playing in the browser. However, in the backend, I see this exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730054
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputSt
ream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:457)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.io.RoutableServletOutputStream.write(RoutableServletOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.writeContent(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.j
ava:407)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.
java:240)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169
)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
        at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.
java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityIntercepto
r.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:1
13)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticatio
nFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMe
AuthenticationFilter.java:139)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextH
olderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:4
5)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthe
nticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebA
syncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistence
Filter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFil
ter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730054
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.addToBB(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.access$000(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:40)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:349)

        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:84)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:256)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
        ... 88 more
```

Is anything wrong or missing ?